# CRON Jobs with PHP

Tags: php, cron

I do link my CRON Jobs to cron.php, which includes the connection etc:

```
<?php
    include "Includes/top.php";
    include "test.php";

    $Test = new Test;
    $Test->update();
?>
```

Then text.php is:

```
<?php
    class Test{
        private $db;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new Connection();
            $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
        }

        public function update(){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO cron (content) VALUES (?)");
            $st->execute(array("ok"));
        }

    }
?>
```

When I visit the link www.*/cron.php it works well and uploads it the database. As I want. but when I activate it with the CRON Jobs id doesn't work at all. My hosting provider tells me that nothing's wrong. So I've to ask, is this the way of doing a CRON Job or am I correct?

Comment: Do you have any more specific detail other that __doesn't work at all__

Comment: It shall be update every 5th minute, but no. It simply doesn't work with the CRONS Jobs, but if I visit the site

Comment: Have you set your cron job to email you the errors? That would be a start

Comment: What does your cron command look like? Note that it has to be something similar to `... /usr/bin/php cron.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes executing php cli is not allowed on shared hosting. Try to execute your script via webserver.

To use curl in cron:

```
/bin/curl http://www.yourdomain.com/cron.php
```

Or use wget:

```
/bin/wget -O - http://www.yourdomain.com/cron.php
```

And let cron send error messages to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the cron.php file in command line what is the response?
Maybe you are using a feature like "curl" which is not activated for php-cli